# How does "Sum" in CloudWatch metrics and alarms work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

[image: CloudWatchAlarm]

Sorry for the large image, but it's the best way to to convey what I'm struggling to understand.
This is a simple alert that should trigger when a lambda generates 10 or more errors within 1 hour. Should be very simple, basic stuff.

So why does this alarm go to ALARM-state when the metric doesn't cross the threshold as shown in the image (green boxes). The new(?) bar at the bottom is the state of the alarm.

All relevant settings should be in the screenshot, its just "sum of errors over 1 hour"

I could just adjust the threshold to account for this weirdness, but I'm guess this is not an AWS-error, but a failure to understand from my part. I want to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this text hidden under an information-icon: "The alarming datapoints can appear different to the metric line because of aggregation when displaying at a higher period or because of delayed data that arrived after the alarm was evaluated."

I guess that is the answer, but I still don't like that the visualization doesn't use the same logic as the alarm. Kind of defeats the purpose.